# Mask Database URL in log file

Tags: security, jenkins, logging, jdbc, flyway

I have a scenario where Jenkins runs Flyway(DB migration tool, similar to liquibase) commands to connect to database and execute the SQL.

The log that gets generated contains the JDBC url string.
This has been masked in Jenkins console output.
But we also redirect the log to a file(to be sent as mail attachment)  in which the URL is not masked which is a risk.

Is there any way the masking can be achieved inside the log file?
Or any way to not print or skip JDBC URL string?

**PS**: We also use logback framework for flyway logging. 
Currently the URL is printed in INFO mode. We do not want to turn INFO mode off, because it has other necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually once the log file gets generated,
I just run sed command to replace the string in the file.

After which the log file is sent as an attachment.

And if you're wondering how to do it on a windows machine, you could use powershell or SED command will be available in cmd if git is installed with below setting,

[image]